# Maximum principle for Poisson equation with Dirichlet condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Assume that function $v$ is satisfying Poisson equation in the circle ($\omega$) with Dirichlet condition on the border ($\partial\omega$):
$$-\mu \Delta v =1\,\,\,\mbox{in}\,\,\omega\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,v=0\,\,\,\mbox{on}\,\,\,\partial\omega\,.$$

How can we deduce by a simple maximum principle the following estimate:
\begin{equation}
|v|_{L^\infty (\omega )} \leq \, \frac{(diam\,\omega)^2}{2\mu}\,? \label{w,1}
\end{equation}

I know that solution has the form $v=\frac{(diam\,\omega)^2-(x^2+y^2)}{4\mu}$ but I don't understand how to get that estimate with maximum principle.

Comment: Take a look at p.3 in this file: http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matdm/ma5245/mp.pdf. There is the proof of estimate you need by means of maximum principle. (Actually, auxiliary function which is constructed there have to look like your solution. However, in general case, when you do not know the exact solution, this method is indeed meaningful.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll check that out! :)